# Is it possible to apply query timeout for native jpa query in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

For HQL query I can do the following:

```
    entityManager.createQuery("update UserSession set userAgent = ''")
            .setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 1)
            .executeUpdate();
```

But if I do the same for native sql query timeout doesn't work

```
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("update user_session set user_agent = ''")
            .setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 1)
            .executeUpdate();
```

Is it possible to apply timeout for native query ?

**Note.**
Preventing possible questions like "Why do you need to update user_session table this way" let me note that in real life I need to execute very complex update query. For this topic exact query is not important.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html#HINT_TIMEOUT

Answer (score 0):

`JPA` spec 2.0+ specifies a STANDARD query hint of

```
"javax.persistence.query.timeout"
```

which can be used with JPQL, NativeQuery or StoredProcedureQuery.
I really don't see the point in using provider-specific hints when a standard one exists.

Comment: This also doesn't work for native queries at least in my version of hibernate (4.1.0).

Comment: so suggest that you raise an issue on your chosen provider as to why they aren't supporting something that is in the spec, and maybe they have a reason.